# Elasticsearch Spring Data integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Im trying to connect Elasticsearch 6.1 using Spring Data (Im using Spring Boot)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But it is mentioned the latest version supports 5.2 only., is there any alternate to support ES 6.1?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest supported version if [5.5.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/pom.xml#L22), but I'm sure 5.6.7 is also supported.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/195) that aims at providing support for ES 6.1 but it is still open as of now.